# Быстрое переключение мониторов

Tags: windows, bat, поиск-программ, монитор

Как изменять состояние `Multiple displays` одной командой?

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как говорится в https://stackoverflow.com/a/16791451/4928642, можно запустить стандартную программу `DisplaySwitch` с одним из следующих параметров:

- `/clone` - Duplicate these displays
- `/external` - Show desktop only on 2
- `/internal` - Show desktop only on 1
- `/extend` - Extend this displays

Соответственно, можно создать нужные ярлыки и запускать их.